# Excel empty fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I need to update the DB based on the fields in excel, but i need to check if 5 fields in a row in one column are empty, then stop updating the DB.

```
                foreach (var sheets in workbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                    var start = sheets.Dimension.Start;
                    var end = sheets.Dimension.End;

                    for (int i = start.Row + 1; i < end.Row; i++)
                    {
                        object columnE = sheets.Cells[i, 4].Value;
                        string aa = columnE.ToString();

                        if (aa.StartsWith("E") && aa.EndsWith("ETO"))
                        {
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnE", columnE);

                            object columnB = sheets.Cells[i, 1].Value;
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnB", columnB);
                        }
                        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(aa) || !aa.StartsWith("E") && !aa.EndsWith("ETO"))
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }

                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        comm.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }
```

I have a logic when the first fields is null or empty or not what is intended to be to stop updating, but i can't find a way to check that for 5 fields in a row.

I have found the solution, here it is for the future people.

```
                foreach (var sheets in workbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    result = sheets.ToString();

                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                    var start = sheets.Dimension.Start;
                    var end = sheets.Dimension.End;

                    int counter = 0;

                    for (int i = start.Row + 1; i < end.Row; i++)
                    {
                        object columnE = sheets.Cells[i, 5].Value;
                        string aa = "";
                        if (columnE != null)
                        {
                            aa = columnE.ToString();
                        }

                        object columnB = sheets.Cells[i, 2].Value;

                        if (aa.StartsWith("E") && aa.EndsWith("ETO") && conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        {                               
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnE", columnE);

                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnB", columnB);

                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            comm.Parameters.Clear();
                        }

                        if (columnE == null)
                        {
                            counter++;
                        }

                        if (counter == 5)
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }                                                                               
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count to 5 where you have true logic otherwise reset the counter to start over.

```
   Int counter =0;
    for (){
    If (logictrue()){
    counter++;
    if(counter==5)
         Update();
    } else 
       counter=0;

    }
```

Comment: I just retweaked your code and got to solution. Everytime coditions are not met i increment the counter, and when counter gets to 5 stop the app. Thank you for the hint

Comment: @Nemanja if it's work for you accept right answer for future users

Comment: I just edited my Question and added the answer. This not really solved my problem but gave me a hint how it can be done.